# How to connect to MySQL db (xampp) using php?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to connect to mysql db in phpstorm, but I don't succeed.
I will appreciate your help.

```html
<?php
$servername = "http://localhost:8012";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
die("Connected successfully");
}
```

The error is:502 Bad Gateway

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: What is the error from `connect_error`? Also try changing your `$servername`value to `localhost`. Your IDE is definitely not the problem

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Likely because you specified an HTTP URL instead of a server name.

Comment: Verify that you have properly installed xampp or whatever you are using and Apache is running as well as mysql

Comment: I checked it.It's not the problem

Comment: DO a `print_r(phpinfo());` and make sure the mysql package is installed

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: Mysqli takes 4 parameters you need to select your database $database = "dbname"; then add this into you mysqli connect

Comment: Edit your question and Add your complete error message please?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect database like that:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$port = "8012";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $port);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
die("Connected successfully");
}
```

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost:8012";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$database) or die(mysqli_error($conn);

echo "Connection Successful";
```